# Xcode 13 Editor inline errors not going away

Tags: xcode, xcode13

Since updating to Xcode 13 yesterday I have noticed that any inline editor warnings/errors that pop up (as they obviously do all the time while writing code) no longer go away as I resolve the warnings. They stay until I actually build.  Even if I restart Xcode they are still there.

Comment: Sometimes Xcode just glitches out. Maybe try `Shift` + `Command` + `K` to clean

Comment: I'm having the same problem: Code checking while typing does not work with Xcode 13 any more. Cleaning the cache /  DerivedData does not help. @rBalmer Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JonasVogel I did not. The problem doesn't come up for errors that occur as I'm writing code, only errors that pop up while building.  Once the errors are fixed I need to build again for them to go away. I'm guessing it is just a bug which will hopefully be fixed soon.